# Circle Distance Question

Tags: python, math

This is my homework question:

> Expand on your Circle class by adding a method called exactly dist() which takes the x and y values of a point, and returns the distance of the point in coordinate space from the outside of the circle (or zero if the point is on or inside the circle).

The following code:

```
myCircle = Circle(1,1,1)
print myCircle.dist(3,4)
```

Should print an output of approximately:

```
2.6055512754639891
```

However I cant understand the question. What does it mean to return the point in coordinate space from the outside of the circle? Can you please explain it?

Comment: do you have a TA you can go to?

Comment: basically, create a method called Circle() that, given an (x,y) point calculates the shortest distance from the point to the edge of the circle.

Comment: If this is "approximate" 2.6055512754639891 I'd like to see the precise answer.

Comment: so it is the distance between ( x and y ) minus the radius

Comment: "exactly dist()" is not a valid method name in Python ;)

Comment: @Ignacio: I bow to you sensai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the distance between the center of the circle and the given point. Subtract the radius from the distance. Negative values are inside the circle.

Comment: By the way, it's not asking you to 'return the point in coordinate space...' It's asking you return 'the **distance** of the point in coordinate space...'

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check if the point is inside the circle on not. Once you've done that, and determined it is outside, you need to find a line [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Normal_line_to_a_curve) to the circle and passing through the point. The length of the line from the circumference of the circle gives you the answer.

**Hint**: Any line passing through the center of the circle is normal to it.

So you have the point `(x,y)`, radius `r` and center `(x0,y0)`. I think you have enough information here to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably means the distance to the closest point on the circle, so its a min-max problem wherre you are minimizing the distance of the point to circumfurance

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from math import hypot
>>> hypot(3-1,4-1)    # How far is the point from the centre of the circle?
3.6055512754639891
>>> hypot(3-1,4-1)-1  # Now subtract the radius
2.6055512754639891
>>>
```

Comment: @yoda, All I can find is this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Do you have a link to this official policy?

Comment: Perhaps _policy_ was the wrong word. Nevertheless, rarely have I seen the the exact solution posted in the HW tag. Moreover, the OP did not request for code, rather an explanation on what the question meant.